# VBA loop function always return 1

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my function, I want to create a function to calculate the rank of number, but it always return 1 in ranking. How to fix it, and add "N/A" before it start.

```
Function Ranking(Score As Double) As Integer

    Dim count As Integer

    Range("C6").Value = "N/A"
    Ranking = 1      

    For count = 1 To num_of_students
        If student_records(count, 3) > Score Then
            Ranking = Ranking + 1      
        Else   
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Range("C6").Value = Ranking

End Function
```

Comment: Your `Exit For` means you stop the loop as soon as a record with score <= `Score` is reached.

Comment: Excel's own `RANK()` function would do the same job, whether on the worksheet or incorporated in your VBA function.

Comment: If you mean `student_records(count, 3).Value` you will find it advantageous - sooner or later - to use syntax that says exactly what you mean. If `Range("C6")` is on the *student_records* tab your loop won't be able to compare "N/A" with `Score`. This function won't work as a UDF because a UDF can't change the value of a cell in which it doesn't reside. If you want to call the function from a worksheet note that `Range("C6")` will be altered on the `ActiveSheet`, meaning the sheet you look at or last looked at. Very dangerous.

Comment: First, I would refactor this and remove the Range("C6") out of the function. Second, create a separate variable called localRanking and increment this instead of Ranking as this is the function itself. After your "Next", return the localRanking from the function by calling Ranking = localRanking. If you absolutely want to initialize your cell from this function and set its value, I'd still use what I suggested but I wouldn't bother using a function and just change it to a method.

Comment: Are `num_of_students` and `student_records` global variables? If so, what are the values?